# Gnuplot - How to make multiple plots and save each one to different files with cairolatex

Tags: gnuplot

I need to make a 2d plot and a 3d plot, which I want to save as `.tex` files, respectively `labo2-mag/latex/position-x-y-over-time.tex` and `labo2-mag/latex/position-3d.tex`. Is there anything wrong with my script ?

```
# General settings
set tics font ", 14"
set tmargin at screen 0.7
set key at screen 0.3, 0.8  font ",14" spacing 1.3 samplen 0.8 box opaque

# set key outside font ",14" spacing 1.3 box opaque
# Send the border to the background
set border lw 0.1 back

set xlabel '$t$ [s?]' offset 1.7;
set ylabel '$Position$ [m?]'  offset -1; 

# Plot once 'in the air'
# set terminal unknown
plot "labo2-mag/data/output.out" using 1:2 with points pointtype 6 lc rgb "red" title '$x(t)$', \
    "" using 1:3 with points pointtype 8 lc rgb "green" title '$y(t)$', \
    "" using 1:4 with points pointtype 6 lc rgb "blue" title '$z(t)$'


# pause 70
# reread
set terminal cairolatex pdf size 10cm, 10cm
set out 'labo2-mag/latex/position-x-y-over-time.tex'
MAX_Y=GPVAL_Y_MAX
MIN_Y=GPVAL_Y_MIN
MAX_X=GPVAL_X_MAX 
MIN_X=GPVAL_X_MIN
set xrange [MIN_X-(MAX_X-MIN_X)*0.1:MAX_X+(MAX_X-MIN_X)*0.01]
set yrange [MIN_Y-(MAX_Y-MIN_Y)*0.05:MAX_Y+(MAX_Y-MIN_Y)*0.05]
replot

# reset terminal

splot "labo2-mag/data/output.out" using 2:3:4 with points pointtype 6 lc rgb "red" title '$pos(t)$'

set terminal cairolatex pdf size 10cm, 10cm
set out 'labo2-mag/latex/position-3d.tex'

replot
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `splot` command is issued while the first terminal is still active and writing to the first output file.  You need to change the terminal and output *before* doing a new plot.  The minimum would be to issue `unset output` after each of your `replot` statements.

You might want or need to also set a new intermediate terminal type together with the `unset output`. I don't understand the "in the air" comment in the script.  Do you mean you don't actually want to plot it?  You want to view it interactively before plotting to a file? Otherwise maybe `set terminal dumb`? If it is relevant, please clarify.